# java script i need help to resolve a quest

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a website and I need do a slidetext. My code is as follows:

```
var quotes = new Array();

quotes[0] = "ola mundo";
quotes[1] = "quote2";
quotes[2] = "quote3";
quotes[3] = "quote4";
quotes[4] = "quote5";
console.log(quotes);
var counter = 0;

function loop() {
    if (counter > 4) counter = 0;
    document.getElementById('textslide').firstElementChild.innerHTML = quotes[counter];
    counter++;
    console.log(counter);
    setTimeout(loop, 2000);
}
loop();
```

and the HTML:

```
<div id="textslide">
<p></p>
</div>
```

When I load the page, I get this error:

```
0x800a138f - Erro de runtime de JavaScript:You Can not Get to property ' firstElementChild ' of a reference not set null OU
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I pasted you code directly into jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gyuj5yrt/ and it works fine. Whats the problem?

Comment: FYI: Java is not JavaScript.

Comment: Put script tag after your HTML.

Comment: or call your function in the document's [`load`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load) event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error means that `document.getElementById('textslide')` didn't resolve, meaning that your document (DOM) isn't fully loaded.

Make sure your DOM is ready before executing your JavaScript function:

```
<body>
  :
  <div id="textslide">
  <p></p>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // your JS code here or in the <head> element
    window.onload = loop;
  </script>
</body>
```

And remove the call to `loop` from your JS code.

There are [several ways](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp) to catch the load event.

If you do not want to use the `load` event, make sure your JavaScript code is that bottom of the `body` element.

Answer (score 0):

TY and look 
the code i was use is that

```
<div id="textslide">
  <p></p>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // your JS code here or in the <head> element
        var quotes = new Array();

quotes[0] = "ola mundo";
quotes[1] = "quote2";
quotes[2] = "quote3";
quotes[3] = "quote4";
quotes[4] = "quote5";
console.log(quotes);
var counter = 0;

function loop() {
    if (counter > 4) counter = 0;
    document.getElementById('textslide').firstElementChild.innerHTML = quotes[counter];
    counter++;
    console.log(counter);
    setTimeout(loop, 2000);
}
loop();
    window.onload = loop;
    window.onload = loop;
  </script>
```

is like that u are say?

Comment: Remove the `loop();` line and have only one `window.onload = loop;` line.